# Is there a connection between The Double Life of Veronique and Three Colors: Blue (besides the music)?

Tags: three-colors-trilogy, three-colors-blue

In The Double Life of Veronique, I got the hint that Veronique's mother died in a car accident (it isn't revealed explicitly, but there is that scene of looking at a wrecked car, and the final scene of her stopped in her car and touching a tree).

In Three Colors: Blue, the main character's husband and little daughter die in a car accident at the beginning but she survives.

Given Kieslowski's penchant for exploring alternate timelines, perhaps Blue is the "alternate" version of The Double Life of Veronique, in which the opposite happens? Is this a known theory and/or referenced by any of the filmmakers?